# How to count results with SQLAlchemy Select API?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

All answers to this question (i.e. counting results from queries in SQLAlchemy) that I could find, where given for Query API. But in my application I am using AsyncSession which does not support query and I have to use select. I have no idea how to get count of all results from query using select API as count() simply does not work.

My code so far:

```
    q = (
        select(User)
        .order_by(User.id)
    )
    if user_type:
        q = q.where(User.user_type == user_type)
    if name:
        q = q.where(User.name.contains(name))
    if surname:
        q = q.where(User.surname.contains(surname))
    if email:
        q = q.where(User.email.contains(email))

    result = await self.db_session.execute(q)
    results = result.scalars()

    return results
```

What I'd like to achieve is something like:

```
count_results = results.count()
```

and return them alongside with list of retrieved objects. Thank all of you in advance!

Comment: `len(results.all())`

Comment: `len(results)`?

Comment: Posted an answer but did you intend for the `.where()` clauses to be combined with `AND` or with an `OR` ?  If you chain `where()` like that it is an `AND`, ie. `users.user_type == {} AND users.name LIKE "%{}%"`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use func.count from the core API either with OR without an argument: [sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count)

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

q = (
        select(func.count(User.id))
        .order_by(User.id)
    )
#...
```